# inline blocks or partials, and parameters (LinkedIn Dust)

Tags: dust.js

I simply can't figure out if this scenario is supported:

- Single template file
- Defined inline re-usable block or partial that can accept parameters
- Main body that calls block/partial passing param values

I know the tag openers are quite likely incorrect.

Really hope you can do this.  I need this supported as users can define their own page templates that will be rendered with LinkedIn Dust and it is painful to force them to define separate page templates for reusable things

e.g.

```
{<reusable_block} {passed_in_param}{/reusable_block}
{! Main content !}
#1. Output of reusuable_block: {>reusable_block passed_in_param="smoo" /}
#2. Output of reusuable_block: {>reusable_block passed_in_param="smee" /}
```

**Edit (self answered)**:

Passing parameters/overridding context for inline blocks not currently supported, hack of sorts in answer below.

Comment: Feature pull request here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/pull/358

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario is not currently supported.

But it can be simulated with more verbosely.

Viewing the SlideShare http://www.slideshare.net/veenabs/curious-case-of-dust, which then led me to the gist for @partial (https://gist.github.com/vybs/3083847), which led me to a workable solution:

```
{<tag}{smoo}{/tag}Hello {name}, {@partial smoo="123"}{+tag /}{/partial},{@partial smoo="456"}{+tag /}{/partial}
```

Ideally in the future they will add support for {+tag smoo="1234" /} which becomes a substitute for {@partial ...}{+tag /}{/partial} logic.

Ultimately I ended up adding async support to a fork of Swig as I prefer the syntax.

Comment: One and a half year has passed by and still it is not supported =/